# SharePoint and Teams client recognize team, Teams Admin portal and M365 Admin center do not

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, azure-ad

I have a team that was created recently using the Teams admin portal. SharePoint online site for the team shows it is connected to Teams (the icon attached to the site title works fine, the Teams column in the SharePoint admin portal indicates the site is Teams enabled). In the Teams desktop client, the team shows up properly and works fine. It also shows up as a Teams enabled group in Azure AD. However - the team does not show in the Teams Admin portal under Manage Teams, and in M365 Admin Center the group does not show as Teams enabled. So we can use the team just fine, we just can't manage the team.

Any thought on how to reconnect or correct this?

TIA
John R